# How to rotate a image in Python tkinter Window

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, loading

I am working on a python messaging application using tkinter and i need a loading screen animation but none of them where fitting with my purpose so i Tried to rotate a image in python continusly which will look like a animation.

[This is the image i want to ratate for some time in tkinter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LcRl.png)
[The application code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BN0ly.png)
i only need a simple tkinter window with the rotating screen

I tried google and i got this code to rote a image

```
from PIL import Image # Import Image class from the library.

image = Image.open("file.jpg") # Load the image.
rotated_image = image.rotate(180) # Rotate the image by 180 degrees.
rotated_image.save("file_rotated.jpg")
```

So i tried using this code like this:-

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

root = Tk()

c = Canvas(root, width=700, height=700)
c.pack()


while True:
    
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r"Loading_Icon.png"))
    c.create_image(100, 100, image=img, anchor=NW)
    
    image = Image.open(Loading_Icon.png") # Load the image.
    rotated_image = image.rotate(30)
     
    os.remove("Loading_Icon.png")
    rotated_image.save("Loding_Icon.png") 
    
    root.mainloop()
    c.delete("all")
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code, you're not providing a problem? If you run it as is you'll most likely get `SyntaxError` because of a badly placed " at the line `rotated_image = ...`, but I am guessing that's not the problem?

Comment: Please post as text not sxreenshot.

Comment: You shouldn't continually rotate the same image because you will get artefacts. The best solution is to open the image and rotate it `30*i` degrees every `x` seconds in a `tkinter` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

# Load the original image
pil_img = Image.open("pawn.black.png")


def loading_loop(i=0):
    global tk_img
    print(f"Loop {i}")

    # If the prgram has loaded, stop the loop
    if i == 13: # You can replace this with your loading condition
        return

    # Rotate the original image
    rotated_pil_img = pil_img.rotate(30*i)
    tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(rotated_pil_img)

    # put the rotated image inside the canvas
    canvas.delete("all")
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=tk_img, anchor="nw")

    # Call `loading_loop(i+1)` after 200 milliseconds
    root.after(200, loading_loop, i+1)


root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

# start the tkinter loop
loading_loop()

root.mainloop()
```

It loads the original image then it start a [`tkinter` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/459131/11106801) which runs `loading_loop` every 200 milliseconds. Inside `loading_loop`, I rotate the image `30*i` degrees, where `i` is the iteration number. Then I put the image inside the canvas.

Notice how I only call `.mainloop()` once and there is no `while True` loop. Those are best practises for when using `tkinter`.

It's best to create only 1 image inside the canvas and just reconfigure it but that will make the code longer.